# Changing the table cells font to be bold

Tags: html, css

I am working with a web template which I download. So I define a table such as:-
table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th> <th></th>
 </tr></thead>
<tbody> 
 <tr> 
        <td class="center" >
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountDefinition.ORG_NAME) 


        </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccountDefinition.ORG_NAME)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td class="center">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountDefinition.LOGIN_URI)


        </td>
```

I search the template for `.center` class, but I can not find any other reference to .center except insidethis

```
div.center,p.center,img.center{
margin-left: auto !important;
margin-right: auto !important;
float:none !important;
display: block;
text-align:center;

}
```

So I added

```
font-weight:bold
```

to the above css so it looks as:-

```
div.center,p.center,img.center{
margin-left: auto !important;
margin-right: auto !important;
float:none !important;
display: block;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;

}
```

But still the table cells font will not be bold? Any idea about how to fix it?
BR

Comment: check to your font family or add body{font-family:arial;}

Answer (score 6):

You have applied the bold style to `div`, `p` and `img` tag.
And you are using it into td tag so change the following line:

```
div.center,p.center,img.center{
```

with this:

```
div.center,p.center,img.center,td.center{
```

**EDITED:**

If you want to make the text align center and bold that then add the below css in your css code:

```
td.center{
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: if i add the td.center ,, then the table format will be wrong all the row cells will be under each others ?

Comment: @johnG so you only want to bold the text and center align the text.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS selector that you have, doesn't apply to `<td>` elements. As you can see from the selector, it only applies to `<div>`, `<p>` and `<img/>` elements. You could add this:

```
td.center {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Or add it to the existing CSS selector:

```
div.center, p.center, img.center, td.center {
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    float:none !important;
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: so why they are referring to the Center class inside a TD, while they did not have related class in the CSS file ?

Comment: I suppose only the developer can answer that. Maybe they intended to add the CSS at some point but never got around to it, or they no longer wanted center alignment on table cells and so remove the `td.center` from the selector.